# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation moves UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I have a custom `UIView` (with a custom xib) and with four `UILabel`, and I want to rotate them 90 degrees with this code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self rotateToLandscape];
}

- (void)rotateToLandscape
{
    NSLog(@"Label 1: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label1.frame));
    NSLog(@"Label 2: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label2.frame));
    NSLog(@"Label 3: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label3.frame));
    NSLog(@"Label 4: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label4.frame));

    self.label1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 1: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label1.frame));
    self.label2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 2: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label2.frame));
    self.label3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 3: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label3.frame));
    self.label4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 4: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.label4.frame));
}
```

But, I don't why, all occupying the same position.

This is the log that I get:

```
Label 1: {{15, 0}, {71, 21}}
Label 2: {{15, 29}, {71, 21}}
Label 3: {{15, 58}, {71, 21}}
Label 4: {{15, 78}, {71, 21}}
Label 1: {{40, -25}, {21, 71}}
Label 2: {{40, 4}, {21, 71}}
Label 3: {{40, 33}, {21, 71}}
Label 4: {{40, 53}, {21, 71}}
```

I read that I have to rotate the `UILabel` from its center (or from its upper left corner), but I don't know how to do it.

This is what I get:

[image]

And, If I show the center to log:

```
- (void)rotateToLandscape
{
    NSLog(@"Label 1: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label1.center));
    NSLog(@"Label 2: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label2.center));
    NSLog(@"Label 3: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label3.center));
    NSLog(@"Label 4: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label4.center));

    self.label1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 1: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label1.center));
    self.label2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 2: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label2.center));
    self.label3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 3: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label3.center));
    self.label4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    NSLog(@"Label 4: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.label4.center));
}
```

I get this log:

```
Label 1: {50.5, 10.5}
Label 2: {50.5, 39.5}
Label 3: {50.5, 68.5}
Label 4: {50.5, 88.5}
Label 1: {50.5, 10.5}
Label 2: {50.5, 39.5}
Label 3: {50.5, 68.5}
Label 4: {50.5, 88.5}
```

Without rotation:

[image]

These labels are inside on an `UIView` and I think I have to rotate that parent view, instead of rotate each `UILabel`.

**Any advice? Do I have to move each `UILabel` after rotation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

Instead of rotate each `UILabel` I have to rotate parent `UIView`:

```
- (void)rotateToLandscape
{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try and look at the documentation for the `frame` property.

> **Warning:** If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

This means that the frame values you are printing after applying the rotation transform could be anything at all. Don't rely on that value. You could look at the `center` property if you want to know the position of the label.

By default all views *are* rotated around the center. You change it using [the anchor point](http://blog.ideveloper.tv/understanding-the-anchor-point/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you can see and very new on this, do you know if there is an example where I can learn how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel **What is "it"?** Rotate around the corner? The method in your code is called `rotateToLandscape` but you shouldn't do that yourself, just configure the view controller to allow both landscape and portrait.

Comment: Thanks, but this not answer my question.

Comment: @VansFannel Then what is your question? "Any advise?"

Comment: I have updated my question, but I think I have found how to solved it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VansFannel Haha, that was not obvious in the original question. Glad that you managed to solve your own problem.